# Retain Style Properties on postback

Tags: asp.net, autopostback

I have a div and 4 drop-down controls.

Default div is hidden using `Style="display:none"`.

First drop-down don't have autopostback event.

Div's display property is changed on few values of 1st drop-down. Once its is visible. User can change values in drop-down field 2/3/4 which is having auto postback true.

As user changes value in any of the 2-5 drop-down controls, postback triggers and set the display property of that Div to `Style="display:none"`.

How can I retain display property of div.

This is on .aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles are not part of the data that are contained in the PostBack. In order to include them, you can create a hidden field on the page that you also set whenever your client code changes the visibility of the div.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
```

When the PostBack arrives at the server, you evaluate the `Value` property of the hidden field and set the style on the `div` so that it matches the state that was stored in the hidden field. In order to be able to change the style on the `div` in .NET code, you need to make sure that `runat="server"` is specified:

```
<div ID="myDiv" runat="server">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

### Sample

The following sample shows how you can use a hidden field to transfer the visibility to the server and restore it on the client. In ASPX, there is the `div`, the hidden field to store the visiblity and a script that sets the visiblity of the `div` and also the value of the hidden field:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="display:none;">
        Div is visible
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="myHidden" runat="server" />
    <input type="button" value="Toggle visiblity" onclick="javascript:toggleDiv()" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Postback" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleDiv()
        {
            $(myDivId).toggle();
            $(myHiddenId).val($(myDivId).css('display'));
        }
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Important to note is that the `div` and the hidden fields get special ASP.NET client ids that do not necessarily match the ids of the tags in the ASPX-file. Therefore, I register a startup script that defines variables with the ids (`myDivId` and `myHiddenId`):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "DivId", 
        "var myDivId = '#" + myDiv.ClientID + "';" + Environment.NewLine + 
        "var myHiddenId = '#" + myHidden.ClientID + "';", 
        true);
}
```

When a postback occurs, the value of the hidden field is transferred to the server and can be used. I've defined a `PreRender` event handler, that restores the visibility of the `div`:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myHidden.Value))
        myDiv.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "none";
    else
        myDiv.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = myHidden.Value;
}
```

Comment: You mean, In hidden field I should copy the value of my text control? And evalute it in server side code, right?

Comment: @Gaurravs: no, I mean that you store the visibility state of the `div` also in the hidden field so that it is transferred to the server. If you make the `div` visible in JavaScript, set a special value into the hidden field. During a postback, on server-side you can read the value of the hidden field and set the visibility of the `div`. When the page arrives on the client, the `div` is visible again.

Comment: @Gaurravs I've added a sample that shows the main parts of the solution. I hope this helps.