# Check html field hidden or not using C# backend code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following code in which I am showing and hiding html controls based on Dropdown list selected value. Show and Hide is working fine but I want to Check in backend i.e C# that the which `<tr>` is visible and which one is hidden.

Here is my aspx page code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#AttachemntType").change(function () {

                 if ($(this).val() == "F") {
                     $("#tr_CompileFile").show();
                     $("#tr_SourceFile").show();
                 }
                 else if ($(this).val() == "R") {
                     $("#tr_CompileFile").hide();

                     $("#tr_SourceFile").show();
                 }
                 else {
                     $("#tr_SourceFile").hide();
                     $("#tr_CompileFile").hide();
                 }
             });
         });
    </script>
                 <tr bgcolor="white">
                    <td style="height: 20px">
                        Attachment Type
                    </td>
                    <td>
             <select id="AttachemntType" name="AttachemntType" style="width: 344px">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="F">Form</option>
                <option value="R">Report</option>
            </select>  
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr bgcolor="white" id="tr_SourceFile" style="display:none;" runat="server">
                    <td style="height: 20px">
                        Source File
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="body_text" type="file" id="src_File" name="src_File" runat="server"
                            style="width: 420px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>


                  <tr bgcolor="white" id="tr_CompileFile" style="display:none;" runat="server"> 
                    <td style="height: 20px">
                        Compiled File
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 16px; width: 625px;">
                        <input class="body_text" type="file" id="comp_File" runat="server" style="width: 420px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

This is the code which I am trying in Backend but its returning always true for all fields

```
  if (tr_CompileFile.Visible == true && tr_SourceFile.Visible == true)
       {
    //This Condition is always true
    }
     else if (tr_SourceFile.Visible == true && tr_CompileFile.Visible == false)
     {
    //something
    }
    else
    {
    //something else
    }
```

Comment: you cannot check the state of any control in backend till you added runat=server with it in html

Comment: Please see this answer of mine for a question some days ago. It is basically the same problem and the answer contains a sample that shows how to solve it. Let me know if you have any questions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35412133/642579

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to do it with patch..

Comment: okay thanks but still I am puzzeled in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually check this in backend. .show() and .hide() are jQuery methods which only operates on client side.

One workaround could be to use a MVVM pattern with knockout.js (Don’t try angular for that, you’ll be lost in docs)

Another option is to actually put your select box and the hidden/visible parts into UpdatePanel. So when you change the selector, the server side is called and you can assign / remove “visible” field.

More : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

In last resort, you can put a hidden field, which will be populated on submit with “hidden,shown,etc” values for you inputs.

Personally, I’ll vote for the first, but second is the easiest one to implement

Comment: ok apart from hiding and showing div can I come to know that which index is selected in my backedn code ??   <select id="AttachemntType" name="AttachemntType" style="width: 344px">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="F">Form</option>
                <option value="R">Report</option>
            </select>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jurion was right. just adding more explanation: you can try

```
tr_CompileFile.Style["HTML Style key here"]
```

for example you can try

```
tr_CompileFile.Style["display"]
```

but it will return to you the value of the particular style defined in your aspx files, not the actual style displayed and changed in client side.

If you defined

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```

when you check it,

```
btnTest.Style["display"]
```

will return "none"

Comment: Is there anyway to get the actual style displayed and changed in client side ?

Comment: No, as Jurion described, you can't. The backend(C#) communicate with your html code through a form (that's why it's called Web Form Application). You can try using a flag to indicate whether an element should be hidden or not (value of a hidden web control)